# How to save data in JSON file using JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {
    name: 'Dhayalan',
    score: 100
};

localStorage.setItem('gameStorage', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to store using Javascript any data into a local file.